# C# WPF alphanumeric cells return empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cell, string

I want to update some data in MySql from a DataGrid when I edit it's rows. The problem is that cells containing both alphabet and numeric characters return empty values when I get them.

I use the following code:

```
TextBlock txt = dgwDataMain.Columns[dgwDataMain.Columns.IndexOf(col)].GetCellContent(dgwDataMain.Items[e.Row.GetIndex()]) as TextBlock;
value += col.Header + "<&p>" + txt.Text + "</s&p>";
```

Columns are dynamically generated:

```
foreach (Fields field in fields)
                {
                    DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    column.Header = field.name;
                    column.Binding = new Binding(field.name) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
                    dgwDataMain.Columns.Add(column);
                }
```

Comment: Poor, bad, horrible idea; time to redesign. Consider Entity Framework or some sort of encapsulation of your data between UI and DB. Don't *ever* shoot data from UI directly to DB.

Comment: Users will work on a table that updates in real time. When they edit a cell the data should be updated into MySql.

Comment: this is no reason to use the most widely advised-against way of implementing it. In a well implemented app you'd have several layers between the UI and the DB. At the very least you should have encapsulated model of your data which can be updated directly through UI and passed along. This lets you do weird things... like validation, caching, grouping of data access operations, did I mention validation? Your app will be screaming SQL Injection

Comment: I don't understand a thing :)

Comment: I can see that :). Basically you don't want to let the user use your form and instead of "John" in their name column enter "';DELETE * FROM MYDATABASE'S TABLE". Learn about Entity Framework, it's very easy to use for basic things and it generates a model for you from the database (or the other way around)